# How to read xml files with different rowTag in a folder in parallel using Spark

Tags: java, xml, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark-xml in Java to read XML files. And I know spark-xml supports the batch read for the xmls with same structure by giving the rowTag and the folder path, shown below:

```
spark.read()
     .format("xml")
     .option("rowTag", "tag1")
     .load(xml_path);
```

Now I have a folder with 1000 xml files in three different structures, e.g. a, b, c, and I cannot tell which type is it by the file name.

The question is: How can I read all the files into 3 spark dataframes, each for one structure, and how can I parallelize these 3 processes?

Thanks in advance!